# LINQ Multiple Insertion

Tags: c#, linq

I have the under listed function

```
 public bool Card_Gen(int id) {
    Card_Details New_Card = new Card_Details();
    int k =0;
    try
    {
        for (k = 1; k <= id; k++)
        {                                  
                New_Card.Card_Num = CreateMD5Hash(Card_Number()).Substring(0, 12);
                New_Card.Card_Serial = Card_Serial();
                db.Card_Details.AddObject(New_Card);
                db.SaveChanges();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But instead of inserting the index times it only does a single insert.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't `Card_Details New_Card = new Card_Details();` be inside the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. You define your `New_Card` outside the loop, therefore you are only inserting it once on the first loop iteration and updating it on the next ones.

Your code should be:

```
public bool Card_Gen(int id) {

    int k =0;
    try
    {
        for (k = 1; k <= id; k++)
        {                                  
                Card_Details New_Card = new Card_Details();
                New_Card.Card_Num = CreateMD5Hash(Card_Number()).Substring(0, 12);
                New_Card.Card_Serial = Card_Serial();
                db.Card_Details.AddObject(New_Card);
                db.SaveChanges();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled`  to enable flush data in the database.

```
for (k = 1; k <= id; k++)
        {                                  
                New_Card.Card_Num = CreateMD5Hash(Card_Number()).Substring(0, 12);
                New_Card.Card_Serial = Card_Serial();
                db.Card_Details.AddObject(New_Card);
                db.SaveChanges();
                //db.SubmitChanges();
                db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true; 

         }
```

or try using

```
db.Flush()
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But 'db.SubmitChanges()' does not seam to be available method. I'm using framework 4.0

Comment: Can you paste the declaration of you 'db' variable? I need know if you're using dbcontext, entity or someone else

Comment: here is the db declaration 

'School_Entities_ db = new School_Entities_();'

Comment: Check if you have a '.Flush' method, you can use it after of 'db.SaveChanges()' (always into the for loop)

Comment: Try with the `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true` to accept the flush data in the database:

`for (k = 1; k <= id; k++)
        {                                  
                New_Card.Card_Num = CreateMD5Hash(Card_Number()).Substring(0, 12);
                New_Card.Card_Serial = Card_Serial();
                db.Card_Details.AddObject(New_Card);
                db.SaveChanges();
                db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
         }`

Answer (score 0):

You should create new instance of object every time, other wise it will update old rows

```
 public bool Card_Gen(int id) {
    Card_Details New_Card ;
    int k =0;
    try
    {
        for (k = 1; k <= id; k++)
        {
                //creating new object in loop
                New_Card = new Card_Details();

                New_Card.Card_Num = CreateMD5Hash(Card_Number()).Substring(0, 12);
                New_Card.Card_Serial = Card_Serial();

                //edit in these two lines if you are using LINQ2SQL otherwise for other providers your code might be correct 
                db.Card_Details.InsertOnSubmit(New_Card);
                db.SubmitChanges();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: the two methods

InsertOnSubmit(New_Card);
SubmitChanges();

Seams not available methods

Comment: @wale what ORM you are using ? they are for LINQ2SQL.

Comment: I'm using Linq to SQL

Comment: So there is InsertOnSubmit method on your tables and SubmitChanges method on your datacontext

Comment: I don't have any of the two methods

Comment: for being sure this is msdn help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
BTW put your mouse on db, what is it's type?

Comment: @Wale if your code has no compile error just take the renewing point and don't change the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the instantiation of your object inside your for loop? Right now, it looks like youre editing the same object over and over again.

Will edit later with example if necessary, I'm on my phone at the moment.